# HiveQl: extract based on a string

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following table:

```
ID           | Keyword   |     Date

87NB  | skill,love,hate,funny,very funny | 02/19/2004

27YV  | funny,tiger,movie,king | 08/10/2014

92JK  | sun,light,funny,baby  | 06/27/2015

65TH  | moon,cow,bird,car     | 04/22/2017
```

From the above table, i want to obtain ID's of everyone who have "funny" as a keyword. The result would be

```
ID

87NB

27YV  

92JK
```

Comment: 87NB is not part of the expected result ?

Comment: sorry it is..updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use split and then the function array_contains

```
select ID from  yourtable where array_contains(split(Keyword, ","), "funny");
```

Comment: this is returning 0 results

Comment: Select the split without filters and share the result

Answer (score 1):

```
select  ID
from    t
where   find_in_set('funny',Keyword) > 0
;
```

---

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 87NB |
+------+
| 27YV |
+------+
| 92JK |
+------+
```